# Difference between Samsung Galaxy I5800 and I5801

Tags: samsung-galaxy-apollo

What exactly are the differences between the two apart from Orange branding? Also I read that I5801 is the Orange branded one, but the phones in India are not Orange branded but still show as I5801 in 'phone info' in 'settings'.

Answer (score 1):

Besides a few visual differences, the look to be the exact same device. The only differences I see between the 2 spec sheets is the dimensions and weight.

- [I5800 Specs](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i5800_galaxy_3-3395.php)
- [I5801 Specs](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i5801_galaxy_apollo-3432.php)

Comment: Then can I flash my I5801 phone with images released for I5800?

Comment: At first thought, I would say... probably... but I would do additional research and see what other I5801 users are doing.

Comment: I've flashed my Galaxy 3 I5801 successfully using I5800 image and by following steps mentioned at http://theandroidfans.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-install-android-22-froyo-latest.html